How to include c++ redistributable package to installer file in c#
In my c# application, I want to include c++ redistributable packages. When application is installed, these packages should also be installed.
I tried to include them in Installer prerequisites the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 latest version, but still it takes 14" version and throws error as incompatible.
I tried custom packaging. But If I install the app, the packages are not installed.

